# how to false visibility of Data Grid View snippet?

Tags: c#, winforms, visibility

How to false visibility of Data Grid View snippet?
I wan to hide the snippet column in a data grid view in WinForm C#.

Comment: You want to hide a particular column in datagridview ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to hide a particular column in your datagridview

```
DatagGridView.Columns[*Column No/Name*].Visible = false;
```

Comment: if you found this is your solution, you can mark it as answer. thnx

Comment: You should make false this property of grid view RowHeaderVisible.
This will hide the snippet column.